# MS SQL: Do you only index tables with many columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, indices

I have local temp tables and they generally have only two to three columns, can these be indexed?

Comment: Yes. Can you perhaps expand on your question? What are you using these for, etc?

Comment: Why are you using global temp tables? You know this effectively reduces concurrency to exactly 1, right?

Comment: a SP ran by SSIS processing up to 3000 records. by global i mean local...

Comment: I guess the short answer is yes you can Index a temp table. However I'm going to have to agree with @AaronBertrand and recommend you not use Global temp tables.

Comment: yeah not global i mistyped that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for instance with this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID      INT,
    UserName    VARCHAR(50)
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Users_UserID ON #Users(UserID)

CREATE INDEX IDX_Users_UserName ON #Users(UserName)
```

ref: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/create-index-on-temp-table